# Is there a python builtin to create tuples from multiple lists?

Tags: python, transpose, list-manipulation, built-in

Is there a python builtin that does the same as tupler for a set of lists, or something similar:

```
def tupler(arg1, *args):
    length = min([len(arg1)]+[len(x) for x in args])
    out = []
    for i in range(length):
        out.append(tuple([x[i] for x in [arg1]+args]))
    return out
```

so, for example:

```
tupler([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7])
```

returns:

```
[(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)]
```

or perhaps there is proper pythony way of doing this, or is there a generator similar???

Comment: Also take a look at itertools module. itertools.izip() and itertools.izip_longest() return memory efficient iterator achieving same result as zip.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> zip([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7])
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
```

Answer (score 5):

have a look at the built-in zip function http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip

it can also handle more than two lists, say n, and then creates n-tuples.

```
>>> zip([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14])
 [(1, 5, 9, 13), (2, 6, 10, 14)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
zip([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7])

--->[(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)]


args = [(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)]

zip(*args)

--->[1,2,3],[5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use the `zip` function.

Alternativerly we can use list comprehensions and the built-in `enumerate` function
to achieve the same result.

```
>>> L1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> L2 = [5,6,7]
>>> [(value, L2[i]) for i, value in enumerate(L1) if i < len(L2)]
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
>>>
```

The drawback in the above example is that we don't always iterate over the list with the minimum length.